# Solve $\ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms

Solve the following equation for x;

$$\ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0$$

What I did is the following but I'm pretty sure its wrong..

$$\ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0$$
$$\ln(x)=-\ln(x-1)$$
$$e^{\ln(x)}=e^{-\ln(x-1))}$$
$$x=-x-1$$
$$2x=-1$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Note: $e^{-y} \neq -e^{y}$

Comment: Note that $e^{-\ln y}=\frac 1y$ because $\ln \frac 1y=-\ln y$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\ln a+\ln b=\ln(ab)$$
and

$$\ln a=0\iff a=1$$

Answer (score 3):

**one of the correct ways is:**

> $$ 
> \ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0 \iff \ln(x)=-\ln(x-1)\overset{note\ *^1}{\iff} \ln(x)=\ln\Big({1 \over x-1}\Big)\\
>  \ln(x)=\ln\Big({1 \over x-1}\Big) 
> \iff \begin{cases} x={1 \over x-1}\\x-1>0\\x>0 \end{cases}
> \iff \begin{cases} x^2-x-1=0\\x>1 \end{cases} \iff x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
> $$

### ALTERNATIVE: (shorter)

> $$ 
> \ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0 \iff \begin{cases} \ln(x(x-1))=0\\x-1>0\\x>0 \end{cases} \iff \\ 
> \iff \begin{cases} x(x-1)=1\\x>1 \end{cases} \iff x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
> $$

---

all in all the most remarkable thing about that equation is that it has the golden ratio as his solution.

---

> **note $*^1$**:
>   $
> -\ln(a)=\ln(1)-\ln(a)=\ln\Big({1 \over a}\Big)
> $

Comment: Why not $\log(x(x-1))=0$ with $x>1$ and $x>0$?

Comment: I'd use the *main* property of the logarithm, first.

Comment: that's good 2 'now! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way:

$0
=\ln (x) + \ln(x-1)
=\ln(x(x-1))
$.

Taking $\exp$
of both sides,
$1 = x(x-1)$
or
$x^2-x-1=0$
so
$x 
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2}
=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}
$

Comment: Ehm, there's a wrong solution. If $x<0$ there's no $\log x$.

Comment: Not true as there is Euler's identity of $e^{\pi i}=-1$ which would be a special case to note.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a small error in your post. It's this part here:

$$
-\ln(x-1)=\ln[(x-1)^{-1}]=\ln{\frac 1 {x-1}}
$$

Because $a \ln b = \ln{b^a}$. So,

$$
e^{-\ln(x-1)}=\frac 1 {x-1}
$$

Having established that and using your exact method of solution it would be:

$$
\ln(x)+\ln(x-1)=0 \\
\ln(x) = -\ln(x-1) \\
e^{\ln(x)} = e^{-\ln(x-1)} \\
x = \frac 1 {x-1} \\
(x-1)x=1 \\
x^2-x-1=0 \\
x = \frac {1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}
$$

Of course, $x>1$ for the logarithms to be defined so one solution does not satisfy the initial equation. So,

$$
x = \frac {1 + \sqrt 5}{2}
$$